# jQuery Dropzone Clickable blueimp

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I was using the dropzone effect, I've done everything correctly, my question is instead of having a Add Files button, I wish to make the dropzone area clickable (the div)

E.g.

```
<div id="dropzone"></div>
```

I wish to make that clickable so I tried.

```
<div id="dropzone><input type='file' name='files' multiple>
```

However this shows an ugly Browser field over my div. Is there anyway to remove that and just make the div clickable to show the select files dialogue?

Answer (score 1):

**In HTML**

```
<div id="dropzone><input type='file' style="display:none" name='files' multiple></div>
```

In JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#dropzone").on("click",function(){// here when click on dropzone div
$("#dropzone input[type='file']").trigger('click');// then trigger input type=file change event 
});


});
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/pTXM3/6/ and apply in your page jsfiidle not allow system popup

Comment: Hi, i've tried it,doesn't work on my page... and it does allow popup (try adding <input type="file" name="files"> it works)

Comment: `$("#dropzone input[type='file']").on("click",function(){ e.stopPropagation(); });`

Need to add this otherwise you cause infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

In Html: move file input outside dropzone and add an id:

```
<div id="dropzone></div>
<input type='file' style="display:none" id="selectFiles" name='files' multiple>
```

in JS: Call click on selectFiles (outside the dropzone, if selectFiles is inside the dropzone .trigger('click') will also trigger click on dropzone and you will have an endless loop)

```
$("#dropzone").on("click",function(e){
     e.stopPropagation(); 
    $("#selectFiles").trigger('click');
});
```